# Get value of CSS property using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I need to do some `if` logic depending if an element in the DOM has the property `display: none`.

I was looking at `getComputedStyle()` and have come this far:

```
var bla = document.querySelectorAll('#nvk-popup-wapper')[0]
getComputedStyle(bla)
```

This returns an object and if I expand it in Chrome's console I can see a property `display` with a value of `none`. But if I go `bla.display` I get `undefined` whereas I had hoped to get the value of the `display` property for that element.

For a particular element, how do I get the value of the `display` property for that element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
var style = getComputedStyle(bla)
var display =style.getPropertyValue('display');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery :

`$("#some-element").css("display");`

would return the property `display` of the `some-element`

Comment: And add an extra 100KB to your page while you are at it.